# EF Core Code First Deployment - VSTS Pipeline - hospolicy.dll

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a project using asp.net core, Entity framework code first, am trying to run EF migrations as a release step, i was advised to use migrate.exe, yet as far as i knew ef asp.net core doesn't generate migrate.exe file.

Am currently using the below command in the release step. After adding the ef core project's bin folder to the generated artifacts.

Command:

```
dotnet exec 
--runtimeconfig ./HOST.runtimeconfig.json 
--depsfile ./HOST.deps.json Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll
--assembly ./DB_CONTEXT_DLL.dll 
--startup-assembly ./HOST.dll --data-dir ./ 
--root-namespace DB_CONTEXT_NAMESPACE 
--verbose database update --context DB_CONTEXT_CLASS -e development
```

The command step fails with the error: 
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'd:\a\r1\a{Publish articats folder}\drop\EF\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\'.

Am not sure what is the hostpolicy.dll and how to generate it as it isn't generated in the bin folder for the EF core project

Any advice?

Comment: Regarding the command issue, I would like to know is it a VS2015 or VS 2017 core project, can you run that command on local machine? Can you share the detail VSTS build log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the log file)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Entity framework migration during the deploy process. Simple steps:

1. Create a publish profile (e.g. Web Deploy package, right click project=>Publish)
2. General deploy package through **Visual Studio Build task** with `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[profilename];DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebAppCoreEF.zip"` arguments
3. Add deploy task (e.g. Azure App Service Deploy) to deploy this package (You can do it in release)

Comment: This would not take into account any connection string changes that are transformed in the Azure App Service Deploy task, would it?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Not clearly what you mean, can you provide the sample to explain it?

Comment: If you need to transform the config as part of the deployment, and your db migrations happen before the deploy, wouldn't you be migrating the wrong database?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs No, you can open a new thread for this issue.